# How to formulate join queries in domain service class?

Tags: silverlight, linq, ria, domain-service-class

in the domain service class there are two entities which I would like to use in join query: WorkerOnMachine {id(int), WorkerId(int), MachineId(int)} and Worker(WorkerId(int), Name(string)...)

I wanted to create a method in domain service class which returned all workers that operate on selected machine (the worker-machine relationships are stored in WorkerOnMachineTable) the following way:

```
public IQueryable<Worker> GetWorkerByMachineId(int machineId)
        {
            var joinedTable = from wom in this.ObjectContext.WorkerOnMachine
                              join w in this.ObjectContext.Worker on wom.WorkerId equals w.Id
                              where wom.MachineId == machineId
                              select new { w };
            return joinedTable as IQueryable<Worker>;
        }
```

but the method returns an empty list. Does anyone know what is the right way to write the above method in domain service class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use var, it is confusing you.

As written, joinedTables is an instance of `IQueryable<AnonType>`.  Since it is not an `IQueryable<Worker>` the cast by `as` returns null.

Instead, write:

```
IQueryable<Worker> joinedTable = ...
```

Then fix:

```
select w;
```

and finally:

```
return joinedTable;
```

(btw, that join looks good).